# unable to shelve - TortoiseSVN 1.12

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I freshly checkout files from repo browser, I made changes to two files and then tried to shelve it.

SVN says: 
"Subversion reported an error:" 
"No path was shelved"

I am using windows 10.  Is there a way to find the logs, if any, to troubleshoot..?

Comment: Looks like this happens in 1.13 and 1.13.1 too without any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue when I tried to shelve `merge metadata infos` (in TSVN: folder icon with "mi" on it).

It seems SVN doesn’t support `merge metadata infos` at this moment (shelve is still marked as experimental), so, it doesn’t support merge shelving correctly (merge without metadata == no merge tracking).